# PhoneGap Build Application Permissions

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, android-permissions

I am using PhoneGap (Cordova) and cant for the life of me figure out how to specify what permissions the application will require when using the PhoneGap Build service.

From what I have read, PhoneGap Build only pulls information from the config.xml located in the project root, and does not need any platform specific files (I have excluded my platform folder from source control completely). I have managed to find the following line in the PhoneGap sample application to limit the application to the most basic permissions for a PhoneGap application, but I have not idea what format to use for specifying additional permissions.

```
<preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
```

Is there a generic list of permissions PhoneGap uses to abstract the vendor specific permissions, or do I need to keep my vendor directories in source control (which I have read is against best practices).

Comment: you should need additional permissions only when using plugins and plugin automatically update platforms's preference files when they need specific permissions (via plugin.xml).

Answer (score 0):

For permissions, add "features" to your config.xml, for example:

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
```

[PG Build doc](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/configuring_features.md.html#Features)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with it would be start with a blank template. This way there will be no permissions and you can add permissions that you require before compiling the app in phonegap CLI or phonegap build.

Here are few standard plugins, mostly self explanatory ([links for more plugins](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins))

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" source="npm" spec="~1.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-motion" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device-orientation" source="npm" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" spec="~4.1.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" spec="~1.5.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-globalization" source="npm" spec="~1.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media" source="npm" spec="~2.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" source="npm" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-vibration" source="npm" spec="~2.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />
```